# How do I add values to the Line Chart? Pod: 'Charts' in swift

Tags: swift, charts, cocoapods, linechart, ios-charts

```
        let chartView = LineChartView()
        var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0...100{
            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(i*i))
            lineChartEntry.append(value)
        }
        
        let line1 = LineChartDataSet()
        line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
        
        let data = LineChartData()
        data.addDataSet(line1)
        
        chartView.data = data
        
        
        chartView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        view.addSubview(chartView)
```

This is what I have coded so far which works perfectly, except for that I do not know how to add 'lineChartEntry' to my 'line1' variable. I think that the following would have worked a few years ago:

```
let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "")
```

It doesn't work today though.

Comment: this works for me. Which Charts version are you using?

Comment: What I had to do was add each value individually instead of as a set.